# Heroku multiple web processes

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am working with node.js and heroku and would like to have more than one webprocess running.
In the Procfile I have it looking like this:

```
web: node web.js
web: node differentWeb.js
```

However when I run it it will only run the last of the two. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: well obviously you first have to define different ports for the two, they can't both run on port 80. Did you do that?

Answer (score 5):

An application on Heroku can only have one process named `web` that gets routed HTTP requests.  If you need another web process then that would be another application on Heroku.