# Is running multiple web: processes possible?

Tags: heroku, php-pm

Our PHP application runs on apache, however php-pm can be used make the application persistent (no warmup, database connection remains open, caches are populated and application initialized).

I'd like to keep this behaviour when deploying to heroku, that is have apache serve static content and php-pm server the API layer. Locally this is handled using an `.htaccess` Rewrite proxy rule that sends all traffic from `/middleware` to php-pm listing on e.g. port `8082`.

On heroku it would mean running two processes in the web dyno. Is that possible?

If not- are there other alternatives that can be used to handle web traffic through different processes or make a persistent process listen to web traffic?

Comment: See this can't be done, you'd have to run the php and php-pm processes in separate heroku apps. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890856/heroku-multiple-web-processes